# Printing one letter caption only once and matching items alphabetically

Tags: xslt

I know I can read a file into a variable like this:
<xsl:variable name="content" select="document('file.xml')"/>, but how can I do the following:

file.xml:

```
<root>
  <child>Some</child>
  <child>Random</child>
  <child>Data</child>
  <child>Stuff</child>
</root>
```

Using that xml file, I'd like to print:

```
D
 * Data

R
 * Random

S
 * Stuff
 * Some
```

Meaning printing the caption only once and then listing the items alphabetically. I know I can use <xsl:for-each> and <xsl:sort>, but how to do that caption part?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thank you. Muenchian method solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions, depending on what you want to do.  The most well-known is the Muenchen method. This method first defines a lookup table to find all elements that share a particular key by that key.  Then, you iterate over all keys (in some order) and for each key, over all key-values (in some order).

**`<xsl:key>`** can be used to make lookup tables.  If you index of the first letter, you can then retrieve those elements which correspond to a particular letter.

```
<xsl:key name="child-by-first-letter" match="child" use="substring(.,1,1)"/>
```

Now, we can't iterate over all keys in a straightforward manner.  However, we can iterate over all values and *test* whether they're the first value in the lookup table...

```
<xsl:for-each select="child[ generate-id() 
           = generate-id(key('child-by-first-letter', substring(.,1,1))[1])]"/>
    <xsl:sort select="substring(.,1,1)" /> <!--sort by first letter-->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)">
    [...]
```

The above code will execute something only on child tags where the generate-id function returns the same value as the generate-id function does for the *first* element of the list of children with the same first letter.  Since generate-id generates unique id's, this will only return only those children that are "first" in the lookup table for their particular key.

Now, you're almost done: just iterate over all children with that particular first letter:

```
    <ul>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('child-by-first-letter', substring(.,1,1))">
             <!--no sort, we'll do document order-->
             <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is called the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: And if xslt 2.0 processor is available then by all means use the built in for-each-group command (http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSL-Ref/Tutorials/For-Each-Group/feg9.html)

Comment: Oh yes, if XSLT 2.0 is available, jump on that the first chance you get :-) - it's much more intuitive in this and many other things.